# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\temp\pip-build-9s6c_h\pyenchant\

Tags: python, pip, installation, pyenchant

Having trouble installing `pyenchant`:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\temp\pip-build-9s6c_h\pyenchant\
```

I tried using `pip install --upgrade setuptools` but that didn't help at all.

Not sure what to do.

EDIT:

Additional traceback:

```
Collecting pyenchant
  Using cached pyenchant-1.6.11.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\temp\pip-build-farfu_\pyenchant\setup.py", line 212, in <module>
        import enchant
      File "enchant\__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
        from enchant import _enchant as _e
      File "enchant\_enchant.py", line 145, in <module>
        raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError: The 'enchant' C library was not found. Please install it via your OS package manager, or use a pre-built binary wheel from PyPI.
```

Comment: Is there anything else in the stack trace pointing to an error?

Comment: added additional details in the import error

Comment: So it looks like you don't have `enchant` installed based on your output.  If you are running in on Linux you would want to do an `apt-get install enchant` or whatever the package is called.  Same with Mac using `brew` I believe.

Comment: I'm using windows and pip doesn't seem to work well

Comment: Checkout this page and all the comments.  From what I can tell, they haven't made a pip wheel package for this plugin.  https://github.com/rfk/pyenchant/issues/42

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the whl file instead, for exammple:

```
pip install name.whl
```

I also encountered this problem today. Fortunately, I used this method to solve it.

```
pip install basemap-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```